# Mongoose / MongoDB. Cannot save array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

UPD:

Found this finally. The code below is perfectly valid. There was just a destructive update to `Layouts.blocks` in another module...

---

Something very odd is happening here.

Here's a relevant part of the `Layouts` schema

```
blocks: [{
   full: {type: Boolean},
  fields: [{type: String}]
}]
```

And .pre save middleware code of another model

```
Map.pre('save', function(next){
  var that = this;
  var Layouts = connection.model('layouts');
  var openFields = ['one', 'two'];
  Layouts.find({_company: that._company, object: that._id, default: true}, function(err, layouts){
    if (err) return next(err);
    var layout = layouts[0];

    console.log(layout.blocks);

    layout.blocks.set(0, {full: false, fields: openFields});
    layout.markModified('blocks');

    console.log(layout.blocks);

    layout.save(function(err){
      console.log('saved: ', err);
      next(err);
    });
  });
});
```

console.log values are

```
[{ full: true, _id: 54147307f07097462fb93912, fields: [] }]
[{ full: false,
  _id: 54147307f07097462fb93918,
  fields: [ 'one', 'two' ] }]
saved:  null
```

Then i inspect saved layout and get:

```
blocks: [ { full: false, _id: 54147307f07097462fb93918, fields: [] } ],
```

So, `_id` and `full` are saved, but `fields` are not!

Something similar happens if i do direct update with

```
Layouts.update({_company: that._company, object: that._id, default: true},
    {$set: {'blocks.0.fields': openFields}},
    function(err){
      next(err);
  });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to implement the same schema as you specified and tried to update my layout object in three different ways, all of them worked. Here is my implementation and tests. Can't see where you are wrong from the code that you have submitted.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                                              
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/layout-test');                                    

var LayoutSchema = new mongoose.Schema({                                         
    blocks: [{                                                                   
        full: {type: Boolean},                                                   
        fields: [{                                                               
            type: String                                                         
        }],                                                                      
    }],                                                                          
});                                                                              
var Layout = mongoose.model('Layout', LayoutSchema);                             
var LAYOUT_DATA = {                                                                 
    blocks: [                                                                
        {full: true},                                                        
    ],                                                                       
};

// Updating the object, setting the first item of blocks
var test1 = function() {                                                        
    new Layout(LAYOUT_DATA).save(function(err, layout) {                                                             
        Layout.update({                                                          
            _id: layout._id                                                      
        }, {                                                                     
            $set: { 
                'blocks.0.full': false,                                                        
                'blocks.0.fields': ['one', 'two'],                               
            },                                                                   
        }, function(err, nbrOfUpdates) {                                                
            Layout.findById(layout._id, function(err, layout) {        
                if (layout.blocks[0].fields.length === 0) {
                    throw Error();
                }                                                                
            });                                                                  
        });                                                                      
    });                                                                          
};                                                                               

// Replacing the old blocks with a new array                                                                      
var test2 = function() {                                                       
    new Layout(LAYOUT_DATA).save(function(err, layout) {                                                 
        layout.blocks = [{                                                       
            full: false,                                                         
            fields: ['one', 'two'],                                              
        }];                                                              
        layout.save(function(err, layout) {  
            if (layout.blocks[0].fields.length === 0) {
                throw Error();
            }                                                                    
        });                                                                      
    });                                                                          
};         

// Pushing a new object to the blocks array and splicing away the old one
var test3 = function() {                                                      
    new Layout(layout).save(function(err, layout) {                                                 
        layout.blocks.push({                                                     
            full: false,                                                         
            fields: ['one', 'two'],                                              
        });                                                                      
        layout.blocks.splice(0, 1);                                              
        layout.save(function(err, layout) {           
            if (layout.blocks[0].fields.length === 0) {
                throw Error();
            }                                                 
        });                                                                      
    });                                                                          
};
```

Comment: Yeah, i just cannot think of anything that could fail the operation... Even if there's something that could trigger __v error for instance (and there's nothing) it would throw an error somewhere. Anyway, thanks for trying it.